# How access and set property from string variable

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to access and set a property of an Object from a string variable without success.

This is what I have :

```
PanelManager.InventoryPanel.SetActive(boolean);
```

How can I do that if I have `"InventoryPanel"` in a string ?

```
string name = "InventoryPanel";
PanelManager.MY_VARIABLE_NAME.SetActive(boolean);
```

I already check on stack but without find a working solution... Thanks !

Comment: You'll need reflection for that. But this might be a XY problem, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I just don't want to copy paste this line for each attribute I have in PanelManager

Comment: That doesn't explain much. There are ways to do this but without more information it's hard to answer.

Comment: Is your _InventoryPanel_ a `GameObject` in your **Hierarchy**?

Comment: Uhm...why is it such a problem to write the name directly? If you need to change the variable name in the future, Visual Studio allows you to change the name of all references in one go as well.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know whether it's just a VB thing, but you should be able to reference the `name` in the `Controls` collection.

So what you want should be:

```
string name = "InventoryPanel";
PanelManager.Controls[name].SetActive(boolean);
```

Comment: What's Controls ? Unity doesn't understand that

Comment: Hmm, it may be referred to as another name in Unity, it's essentially a collection of objects, I can't remember the name of it in Unity, i'll try find it and have a look, but unity should have something similar

Comment: Edit: just realised that `PanelManager` is a custom object off the asset store, this might make it a bit more difficult.

Comment: PanelManager is a custom class from me

Comment: Okay, and do you have anywhere you store everything inside, like an array or collection?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this using reflection:

```
foreach (var property in typeof(PanelManager).GetProperties())
{
    if (property.Name == "InventoryPanel")
    {
        ((InventoryPanel)property.GetValue(null)).SetActive(boolean);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

Perhaps a more generic solution:

```
public static T GetStaticPropertyValue<T>(Type type, string name) where T : class
{
    foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
    {
        if (property.Name == name)
        {
            return property.GetValue(null) as T;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: However, reflection should be used as a last resort considering the performance costs.